# Combining Knockout.js + KendoUI - What has been your experience?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, javascript, kendo-ui

So I see that KendoUI has included an example of integration with Knockout.js:
http://demos.kendoui.com/web/integration/index.html

However, this looks like a pretty trivial example.

According to this post, it looks like binding to something like Kendo's grid would be much more involved:
http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/grid/knockoutjs-example-for-grid.aspx

It also looks as if they are creating their own MVVM implementation to try and solve the issues.

Has anyone here used KendoUI and Knockout.js for non-trivial apps using some of the more complex components?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've been doing a lot of research into integrating KO and Kendo. I have the utmost respect for the folks at Telerik and they make great products. I expect great things from Kendo. At this time, integrating KO and Kendo is not straightforward. For example, their KO example on the Kendo web site itself has a bug in it. Where is this heading? The Kendo team is considering some options on how to integrate better with KO ... what I "think" they key would be is to hook into KO's subscriptions so Kendo can be notified when changes occur. One way to do this is for Kendo to create KO binding handlers for their control suite. In fact, this does work, but its obviously something they have to put time to dev, test, and support . So I don;t know if they will or wont do that.

I'm happy to elaborate on the integration issues, but I dont want to go down a rabbit hole if you dont want to :)

Kendo is working on some ideas for an MVVM solution of their own. The idea would be to have an MVVM solution that works with Kendo or any other javascript library. I look forward to seeing what they come  up with.

The net result is for now, i am not trying to integrate the 2 suites personally. I've chimed in with my 2 cents to Kendo to ask them to support KO integration. I encourage you to do so too :)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback John!  I've only used Knockout for a short while but I've grown very fond of it.  I'm sure a lot of people would love to see these 2 libraries come together.

Comment: Make sure you let Kendo know that :)

Answer (score 4):

Just in cased you missed it, I wanted to bring to your attention a very interesting project on the works called Knockout-Kendo.js (at http://rniemeyer.github.com/knockout-kendo/), which "... creates a complete and robust set of Knockout.js bindings for the Kendo UI widgets..."

This project was mentioned on "KendoUI Day"; although that was the same day they demoed their new MVVM library; I really like knockout, I wish they would have worked more on integration than on creating their own library.

Anyways, I hope this helps,
-Covo

Comment: Thanks for the tip - already got the repo forked.  Definitely looking forward to seeing more from this.  I'm currently using Kendo's own mvvm - which is pretty nice as well.