# Choosing knockout or kendo

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, mvvm, knockout.js, kendo-ui

I have requirement to use kendo controls for my application as well as mvvm bindings.

I went through this articles

[article 1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/574261/ComparingplusKendoUIplusandplusKnockoutplus-withpl)

[article 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823681/combining-knockout-js-kendoui-what-has-been-your-experience)

and found that all articles are aligned to kendo. Could you please let me know why so and could you please share the advantages and disadvantages?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use both together, Knockout and Kendo (with MVVM), You just need to use `Knockout-Kendo.js`.

- [Knockout-Kendo.js](http://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/) is a project to create a complete and robust set of `Knockout.js` bindings for the `Kendo UI widgets`. [Examples](http://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/web/Button.html) and Configurations available [there](http://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/) itself.

[Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) is an open source library that supports declarative data binding, dependency tracking, and automatic UI updates.

[Kendo UI](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui), by Telerik, provides fast, clean, and configurable HTML5 UI widgets as part of a jQuery-based framework to support modern web development.

Note: [#2 Article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823681/combining-knockout-js-kendoui-what-has-been-your-experience/10096650#10096650) link has the Answer ([Answered By Covo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/482033/covo)).

I would suggest you to use both together (Knockout (MVVM) and Kendo with Knockout-Kendo.js), Since Knockout-Kendo.js is very much matured to use.